# UINavigationController crash

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I spent some time debugging this, but out of ideas.. maybe I am missing something but these are the sequence of things which happens to the navcontroller. Each step happens when the user does something :

1. NavController top viewController is TopVC.
2. [navController presentViewController:controller animated:animated completion:^(void) {}];
3. [navController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
4. [navController pushViewController:VC1]
5. [navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^(void) {}]
6. [navController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
7. [navController pushViewController:VC2 animated:YES];
8. [self.navigationController popToViewController:TopVC animated:NO];
   and then go to #1 above.

This flow works for the first time around, but when the user clicks the button after step #2, The call #3 call causes a crash.. After enabling Zombies, it somehow references VC2!

The series of steps above is exactly what I do in the code. The crasher :

```
2014-07-30 13:22:01.662 MyApp[41037:60b] *** -[MessageViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14d88940

(lldb) bt

* thread #1: tid = 0x29f33d, 0x02741411 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 769, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x02741411 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 769
    frame #1: 0x027410ee CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 14
    frame #2: 0x013c3874 UIKit`-[UITextView canBecomeFirstResponder] + 117
    frame #3: 0x00e1e045 UIKit`-[UIResponder(Internal) _canBecomeFirstResponder] + 33
    frame #4: 0x00e1d017 UIKit`-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 242
    frame #5: 0x00d1860e UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 114
    frame #6: 0x013c38e9 UIKit`-[UITextView becomeFirstResponder] + 79
    frame #7: 0x00d1865b UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) deferredBecomeFirstResponder] + 67
    frame #8: 0x00d186ef UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _promoteSelfOrDescendantToFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 115
    frame #9: 0x00d189a9 UIKit`__45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 216
    frame #10: 0x01daa68c Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 107
    frame #11: 0x01c3a3c5 Foundation`-[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 48
    frame #12: 0x00d18830 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 313
    frame #13: 0x00d23dd4 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1875
    frame #14: 0x00d16dba UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    frame #15: 0x00db76f0 UIKit`-[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 1205
    frame #16: 0x01087004 UIKit`__101-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:]_block_invoke_2 + 1472
    frame #17: 0x01085cdc UIKit`-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 8737
    frame #18: 0x00de3bda UIKit`-[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 1647
    frame #19: 0x00de352e UIKit`-[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 1281
    frame #20: 0x00de4729 UIKit`-[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] + 57
```

Comment: 1) Show relevant code. 2) Show details about the crash.

Comment: 3) Never use smileys in the topic title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post some code, it is really hard to figure out what is causing the crash.

When you go back to TopVC on Step 8 [self.navigationController popToViewController:TopVC animated:NO] -> when TopVC loads again and Step 2 is executed the variable "controller" is null and so its causing the crash.

I am assuming you instantiate the "controller" variable in ViewDidLoad. If that is the case, move the code that instantiates "controller" to the viewWillAppear method and try.

Comment: I have updated my original step numbers, somehow it got messed up. After the last step, I do the following and show step #2 :     UIViewController *controller = [[CartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil]; and when the user taps to go to step #3 :     UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [navController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
and the second line crashes.